# Bayes Theorem - Discrete Math

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose that one person in 10,000 people has a rare genetic disease. There is an excellent test for the disease; 99.5% of people with the disease test positive and only 0.06% who do not have the disease test positive.
What is the probability that someone who tests positive has the genetic disease?

$P(A) = 0.0001 ( 1/10000)$  (People having the disease among population)
$P(B|A) = 99.5/100 = 0.995$                (People who are positive)
$P(\bar{A}) = 1 - 0.0001 = 0.9999$ (People who dont have the disease)
$P(B|\bar{A}) = 0.06/100 = 0.0006$  (People who show up positive but dont have the disease)

Using the formula :
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(A)P(B|A)+P(\bar{A})P(B|\bar{A})}$$

We determine that the probability of some who tests positive and has the genetic disease is :

$$\frac{0.0001 * 0.995}{0.0001*0.995 + 0.9999*0.0006}$$
= 0.1422

Is this the right approach to this problem, please advise.

Comment: It would help to know what the events $A$ and $B$ represent in your work.

Comment: Shouldn't $\Pr(B \mid A) = 0.995$ since $99.5\%$ of the people who have the disease test positive for the disease?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig , I think you are correct Sir. Let me change it and work the problem again. Very good catch, I was working of some example solutions, hence didnt understand it quite well. Please verify, when you get a chance.

Comment: Your approach is correct.  $\Pr(B \mid A)$ should be the probability that a person tests positive given that she or he has the disease, while $\Pr(B \mid \overline{A})$ should be the probability that a person tests positive despite not having the disease (false negatives).